# Error when attempting to install hexo

Tags: node.js, hexo

When I installed Hexo, I got this error. I don't know what's happend? Can someone help me?

```
C:\Users\LiuHu>npm install hexo-cli -g
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.5
C:\Users\LiuHu\AppData\Roaming\npm\hexo -> C:\Users\LiuHu\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\hexo-cli\bin\hexo
hexo-cli@0.1.4 C:\Users\LiuHu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\hexo-cli
├── abbrev@1.0.5
├── minimist@1.1.1
├── bluebird@2.9.13
├── tildify@1.0.0 (user-home@1.1.1)
├── chalk@1.0.0 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, ansi-styles@2.0.1, supports-colo
r@1.3.0, strip-ansi@2.0.1, has-ansi@1.0.3)
└── hexo-fs@0.1.3 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, graceful-fs@3.0.5, chokidar@0.
12.6)
```

---

When i run this command `npm install` . it show me this error ：
`D:\Document\Z_MYBlog_New>npm install`

`npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies`

`npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601`

`npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs`

`\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"`

`npm ERR! node v0.12.0`

`npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1`

`npm ERR! path D:\Document\Z_MYBlog_New\package.json`

`npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON`

`npm ERR! errno -4058`

`npm ERR! package.json ENOENT, open 'D:\Document\Z_MYBlog_New\package.json'`

`npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.`

`npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.`

`npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:`

`npm ERR!     D:\Document\Z_MYBlog_New\npm-debug.log`

And in D:\Document\Z_MYBlog_New\npm-debug.log  this log file, it show me :
`0 info it worked if it ends with ok`

`1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',`

`1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',`

`1 verbose cli   'install' ]`

`2 info using npm@2.5.1`

`3 info using node@v0.12.0`

`4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe`

`5 error install Couldn't read dependencies`

`6 verbose stack Error: ENOENT, open 'D:\Document\Z_MYBlog_New\package.json'`

`6 verbose stack     at Error (native)`

`7 verbose cwd D:\Document\Z_MYBlog_New`

`8 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601`

`9 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"`

`10 error node v0.12.0`

`11 error npm  v2.5.1`

`12 error path D:\Document\Z_MYBlog_New\package.json`

`13 error code ENOPACKAGEJSON`

`14 error errno -4058`

`15 error package.json ENOENT, open 'D:\Document\Z_MYBlog_New\package.json'`

`15 error package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.`

`15 error package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.`

`16 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]`

Comment: What error?  Looks fine to me.

Comment: when i input 'hexo' , it show me 'hexo command not fund'. i think hexo does't be installed completely. need i add something in PATH?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## This is a warn not error

I suggest you use the hexo 2.8.Now don't use hexo 3.0.
cause the hexo-server or hexo clean maybe has something wrong that will make you bad.
`npm install hexo@2.8 -g`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I try to install hexo 2.8 . and then input command `hexo version`, it also show me `hexo command not fund` . and i try to add hexo path `C:\Users\LiuHu\AppData\Roaming\npm` into my system path. it is working.

Comment: I  install hexo 2.8.and then input command `hexo version`, it show me `hexo command not fund` . i try to add hexo path `C:\Users\LiuHu\AppData\Roaming\npm` into my system path. it is working. `D:\Document\Z_MYBlog_New>hexo version `
`hexo: 2.8.3                           `
`os: Windows_NT 6.1.7601 win32 x64     `
`http_parser: 2.3`
`node: 0.12.0`
`v8: 3.28.73 `
`uv: 1.0.2  `
`zlib: 1.2.8`
`modules: 14 `
`openssl: 1.0.1l`
But when i input command :
`D:\Document\Z_MYBlog_New>hexo init liuhu`
`[info] Copying data`
`[info] You are almost done! Don't forget to run `npm install` before you start b`

Comment: Just do `npm install`,it will be ok.

Comment: follow it                                                                                                            `$ hexo init <folder>   
$ cd <folder>   
$ npm install`